# What is the function of Zener diodes in an astable multivibrator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit, timer, zener

I came across this schematic in my textbook which has back to back Zener diodes connected to the output of an astable multivibrator using op-amp which apparently varies the peak to peak output amplitude. Would really help if someone could provide a clearer explanation.[image]

Comment: I don't understand much the schematic (does it really oscillate?), but I am not an expert. The zener could "cut" the output wave which, otherwise, could be not enough square.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica The oscillator is the part left of Rsc, the zeners have nothing to do with the oscillator itself. You're correct that the zeners "clip" (limit) the output amplitude to a properly defined value. The oscillator is a "Schmitt trigger oscillator" (Google that). The opamp and resistors form the Schmitt trigger.

Comment: Thank you @Bimpelrekkie; meanwhile I realized that the voltage can dive under 0 (I didn't before), so the *two* anti-series zeners make sense, and the oscillator is more understandable. I wonder if, using only positive voltages, that oscillator could stick at 0 volts.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Yes, as the circuit is drawn, the opamp needs a negative voltage. Without that the oscillator could get "stuck" in a point where it cannot (dis)charge the capacitor enough so that it passes the \$\beta V_o\$ voltage. When there is no negative supply that can indeed happen, it depends on how the opamp responds to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would really help if someone could provide a clearer explanation.

The zeners are there to fix the peak to peak amplitude to +/-(Vz + Vf)

Where Vz is the zener breakdown voltage of one zener and, Vf is the forward voltage of the other series connected zener (because one will be forward biased and one will be reverse biased).

Answer (score 4):

The op-amp part of the circuit is designed to switch from V- to V+ on each cycle. Because the op-amp output stage will  not be perfectly symmetrical the square-wave will not be symmetrical.

[image]

*Figure 1. Internals of the ancient 741 opamp. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op-amp).*

From the internal schematic of the 741 op-amp it should be clear that in this case the output stage is not exactly symmetrical.
For example, if the op-amp is running on a ±12 V supply you might find that the output switches to +10 V and -9 V. This might not be acceptable for certain applications. While the 741 is not used in modern designs the principle still applies.

Notice that there is a resistor, R<sub>SC</sub> between the op-amp and the back-to-back Zener diodes. The combination will form a Zener voltage regulator with R<sub>Z</sub> forming a current limiter to the Zeners. On each half-cycle of the squarewave one will be forward biased and one will be reverse biased so the output voltage will be the sum of these.

Note that there are still some imperfections. Since the positive and negative feedback is taken from the op-amp output it too will suffer from any asymmetry and you might find that the duty-cycle is not quite 50%.